# Removing line breaks in ordered lists using jquery

Tags: jquery

Am getting data from a webservice which is being displayed in the format below

`<ol>\r\n<li>Combine garlic, mustard, chili powder, cayenne pepper, salt and thyme in a    small bowl.</li>\r\n</ol>`

I've been tearing my hair out trying to remove the \r\n but i cant seem to do so. Because there in between elements and not in the content most jquery functions arent working. Am trying out something like:

```
$("*").each(function () { 
  if ($(this).children().length == 0) { 
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace('<ol>\\r\\n<li>','<ol><li>')); 
  }
});
```

Doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need to remove the line breaks? Whitespace won't show up if you append it to the DOM.

Comment: There's no reason to remove \r\n in HTML.  Linebreaks are ignored by HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You could just parse it using [`jQuery`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/).

```
var data = $("<ol>\r\n<li>Combine garlic, mustard, chili powder, cayenne pepper, salt and thyme in a small bowl.</li>\r\n</ol>");
```

You can then use `data` as any jQuery DOM wrapper object. It represents the `<ol>`.

Comment: Please explain this abit further

Comment: I don't see what needs explaining. What do you want to do with this piece of HTML?

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to use a regular expression.

I haven't tested it, but should work

```
$(this).html().replace( /[\r\n]/gm,'')
```

It should strip out every occurrence of \r\n in the html.

The final code should look like this

```
$("*").each(function () { 
  if ($(this).children().length == 0) { 
    $(this).html( $(this).html().replace( /[\r\n]/gm,'') ); 
  }
});
```

**UPDATE**

To fix the script according to your comment, I think the best way would be to wrap the OL in a container and parse its html.

```
<div id="container">
  <ol>\r\n<li>Combine garlic, mustard, chili powder, cayenne pepper, salt and thyme in a small bowl.</li>\r\n</ol>
</div>
```

Script

```
var container = $('#container');
container.html( container.html().replace( /[\r\n]/gm,'') );
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, the result of this expression should be passed to $(this).html() as a parameter like $(this).html($(this).html().replace( /\r\n/gm,''))

I wrote it for the sake of minimizing confusion if anyone reads.

Comment: Sure, I just extracted that portion of code out of the original question :) But you're right, it's somehow confusing, I will update the answer!

Comment: This doesn't work, .html doesn't seem to find the line breaks

Comment: Are you sure you have \r\n and not only \r or \n? I updated the regex and tested it, working. As a side note, notice that you probably won't see any changes in the layout after stripping the line breaks

Comment: I have \r\n. Here's the thing, the code works if the \r\n is inside the list e.g. `<li>\r\n sample text</li>` however in this case the \r\n is in between the lists e.g. <ol>\r\n<li>sample text</li>\r\n<li>more sample text<\li>` For some reason i dont understand the code can't seem to filter out the line breaks

Comment: That's because the script only parse elements without children ( .children().length == 0 ), that means that only the li is parsed.

Comment: Hi david...check out my workaround and tell me what you think of it...it works but not the tidiest or most elegant of solutions!

Answer (score 0):

I coded an untidy workaround which works. Basically getting all text in the ol, replacing the line breaks and inserting the li as replacements. Have to remove the first and last list items as there empty. Not the most elegant solution but it works

`var data = $("#tab-2 ol").text();
        data = data.replace(/\\r\\n/gm, '<li>');
        $("#tab-2 ol").html(data);
        $("#tab-2 ol li:first-child").remove();
        $("#tab-2 ol li:last-child").remove();`